# VB.NET error DatagridViewCellValueChanged Windows 8

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, windows-8, format-conversion

I have this problem that looks very strange, I develop a program which sends only error message on computers with Windows 8, but Windows 7 and Windows 10 works perfectly.

I will discuss a little about the error, in a few lines of code, specifically in the event `DataGridViewCellValueChanged` I convert a number to coin format, but the strange thing is that the event runs (in my opinion) before they change the value of the cell and I think the cellvaluechanged event should be executed when the user typed something in the cell and then out of that cell, something "similar" to CellEndEdit but only when the value of the cell change, but in this specific case the user presses any character in any cell in a column specified without losing the focus of the cell and sends an error.

On my computer with windows 7 program works well and on a Windows 10 too

This is the code:

```
Private Sub GridCatalogo_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles GridCatalogo.CellValueChanged
    If GridCatalogo.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).ToolTipText = "$" Then
        If IsNothing(GridCatalogo.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value) = False Then
            Try
                GridCatalogo.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = Format(CType(GridCatalogo.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value, Decimal), "$#,##0.00")
            Catch ex As Exception
                'MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End If 
End Sub
```

I know that the image of an error message is not needed, but wanted to show the data that the user typed in the DataGridView.

[image]

The message says:

> The conversion from string "$8.00" to 'Decimal' is unsupported.

As you can see in the code, I had to handle the error to stop displaying the message, so only temporarily fix the error but do not understand why that happens only in Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you to debug. You want `s` to be "$8.00" by the time you get to the assignment, and you should have no problem. If the error message shows a value you didn't expect, but it is in the grid at some point after the assignment, then you know you have a timing issue.

```
Private Sub GridCatalogo_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles GridCatalogo.CellValueChanged
    If GridCatalogo.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).ToolTipText = "$" Then
        If IsNothing(GridCatalogo.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value) = False Then
            Dim s As String = "not set"
            Dim d As Decimal = Decimal.MinValue
            Try
                s = GridCatalogo.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value
                d = CType(s, Decimal)
                GridCatalogo.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = Format(d, "$#,##0.00")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(String.Format("s={0}, d={1}, ex.message={2}", s, d, ex.Message))
            End Try
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Your format method probably works, but why not use a currency format? If CurrentCulture doesn't work, you can specify it.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim currencyString = "$8.00"

    Dim currencyOPFormat = Format(CType(currencyString, Decimal), "$#,##0.00")

    Dim currencyDecimal = Decimal.Parse(currencyString, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
    Dim currencyNewFormat = currencyDecimal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

    Console.WriteLine("Original: " & currencyOPFormat)

    Console.WriteLine("Parsed Decimal: " & currencyDecimal)
    Console.WriteLine("Formatted Decimal: " & currencyNewFormat)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

See about currency format: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString

Comment: thank you, even I do not try your code because first I want to understand it better, but what you mentioned me gave me the idea to solve the problem, only I had to change the format in the settings regonal those computers.